# Make Sub-Directory Appear As Sub-Domain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a CMS where the admin system is located in a sub-directory, so it cannot be moved to an actual sub-domain.

Is it possible to make "domain.com/manage" read as "manage.domain.com" in the URL? This includes functions and stuff, ex: domain.com/manage/reports.php?etc should read as manage.domain.com/reports.php?etc

Can this be done with .htaccess and mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 2):

you can use something  like:

```
RewriteRule ^(manage/.*)$ http://manage.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I've been playing with this and cannot get it to work. I even put a .htaccess file with the rule in the admin directory. The site is HTTPS, does that make a difference?